# Voldemort types in C#

Tags: c#, closures, d

As you probably know in D language we have an ability called [Voldemort Types](https://wiki.dlang.org/Voldemort_types) and  they are used as internal types that implement particular range function:

```
auto createVoldemortType(int value)
{
    struct TheUnnameable
    {
        int getValue() { return value; }
    }
    return TheUnnameable();
}
```

Here is how the Voldemort type can be used:

```
auto voldemort = createVoldemortType(123);
writeln(voldemort.getValue());  // prints 123
```

Now I want to make sure that, Is this the equivalent to `delegate` in C#?

```
public static void Main()
{
    var voldemort = createVoldemortType(123);
    Console.WriteLine(voldemort());

}
public static Func<int> createVoldemortType(int value)
{
    Func<int> theUnnameable = delegate()
                              {
                                    return value;
                              };
    return theUnnameable;
}
```

Comment: In C# you'd return an instance of a private class, and the declared return type of your function would be an interface. Not *exactly* the same thing, but close enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't an *exact* equivalent of a Voldermort type in C#. The closest you have to such local scope classes is called Anonymous Types. Problem is, unlike Voldermort types, you can't refer to their static type at compile time outside of the local declaration:

```
public object SomeLocalMethod() // Must return either `dynamic` over `object`
{
    var myAnonClass = new { X = 1, Y = "Hello" };
    Console.WriteLine(myAnonClass.Y); // Prints "Hello";
    return myAnonClass;
}

void Main()
{
    object tryLookAtAnon = SomeLocalMethod(); // No access to "X" or "Y" variables here.
}
```

If however, we enter the land of `dynamic`, you can refer to the underlying class fields, but we lose type safety:

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic tryLookAtAnon = SomeLocalMethod();
    Console.WriteLine(tryLookAtAnon.X); // prints 1
}

public dynamic SomeLocalMethod() 
{
    var myAnonClass = new { X = 1, Y = "Hello" };
    Console.WriteLine(myAnonClass.Y); // Prints "Hello";
    return myAnonClass;
}
```

A delegate in C# is similar to [a delegate in D](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#closures). They hold a reference to a function.

Comment: Anyone know what to expect from future versions of C#?

Comment: @sq33G I don't think C# 7 has any plans for anything of that kind.

Comment: @sq33G Doubt it will ever be introduced into C#